# Search multiple individual text strings, using "text contains" in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-filter

How can I search using the "text contains" filter option in Google Sheets for multiple individual strings of text?

Currently I can search individually for `"amazon"` or `"AMZ"` but I would like to search for both `"amazon"` *and* `"AMZ"`.

What is the syntax to do this? I've tried a couple of variations but can't get it to work.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to Filter by condition\Custom formula and insert following:

```
=MATCH(A2, {"amazon", "amz", "azamon"}, 0)
```

where 
A2 - is cell where your data starts and row you are filtering (in example A1 is header and you filter by first row),
{"amazon", "amz", "azamon"} - list of your conditions.